# Recursively iterate over List/Array

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I am new to reflection, what would be the best way to recursively iterate over objects, that have generic lists and normal arrays as fields containing other objects?

**More information**

Actually I created the following Attribute to mark fields that will be exported for translation:

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class ExportForTranslationAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public ExportForTranslationAttribute() { }
}
```

Then I start at a certain object and go deeper from there.
(I copied the entire method now.)

private Int64 timesMaxDeepnessReached = 0;

```
private void searchForExportableStringsInObject(object obj, int deepness)
{
    if (deepness > maxDeepness)
    {
        timesMaxDeepnessReached++;
        return;
    }

    if (obj != null)
    {
        //only follow serializable objects!
        var objAttributes = obj.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true);
        foreach (var oa in objAttributes)
        {
            if (oa.GetType() == typeof(SerializableAttribute))
            {
                var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
                if (fields == null || !fields.Any())
                { return; }

                foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
                {
                    //1. handle string fields that are directly on the component
                    #region directly on object
                    var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);

                    bool hadExportAttribute = false;

                    foreach (var a in attributes)
                    {
                        if (a.GetType() == typeof(ExportForTranslationAttribute))
                        {
                            Debug.Log("found something!");
                            hadExportAttribute = true;

                            if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Debug.Log("info.GetValue= " + fieldInfo.GetValue(obj));
                                    addKeyWhenNotExisting((string)fieldInfo.GetValue(obj));
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { Debug.Log("error while getting value to export: " + ex); }
                            }
                            else if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string[]))
                            {
                                Debug.Log("found string[]!");
                                try
                                {
                                    Debug.Log("info.GetValue= " + fieldInfo.GetValue(obj));
                                    foreach (var item in (string[])fieldInfo.GetValue(obj))
                                    {
                                        addKeyWhenNotExisting(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { Debug.Log("error while getting value to export: " + ex); }
                            }
                            else if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(List<string>))
                            {
                                Debug.Log("found List<string>!");
                                try
                                {
                                    Debug.Log("info.GetValue= " + fieldInfo.GetValue(obj));
                                    foreach (var item in (List<string>)fieldInfo.GetValue(obj))
                                    {
                                        addKeyWhenNotExisting(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { Debug.Log("error while getting value to export: " + ex); }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Debug.LogWarning("Can only add ExportForTranslation-Attribute to string values and collection of string values. Not on the type: " + fieldInfo.FieldType);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion //directly on object
                }
            }
            else if (oa.GetType() == typeof(List<>))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var item in (IList)oa)
                    {
                        searchForExportableStringsInObject(item, ++deepness);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }//{ Debug.Log("error while getting value to export: " + ex); }
            }
            else if (oa.GetType() == typeof(Array))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var item in (Array)oa)
                    {
                        searchForExportableStringsInObject(item, ++deepness);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }//{ Debug.Log("error while getting value to export: " + ex); }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you swallowing all exceptions?

Comment: I think some more concrete background information what you're really trying to do might be beneficial.

Comment: +1 I agree the question isn't particularly well written, and perhaps it is not entirely clear was is required, but if I have interpreted it correctly I think it does have some merit.

Comment: hope my edit made it clearer..

Comment: sorry, I am working on something completely different. Therefore it might take a while until I can favor an answer definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oa.GetType()` gets you the type of the instance, not the type of the property for which you need `oa.PropertyType`.

EDIT

I may have gone around the houses to put this together and I bet there is a better, or at least more succinct way, but perhaps this is something like what you are looking for:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testType = new TestType {GenList = new List<string> {"test", "type"}};

            foreach(var prop in typeof (TestType).GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var genericTypeArgs = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

                    if (genericTypeArgs.Length!=1 || !(genericTypeArgs[0] == typeof(string)))
                         continue;

                    var genEnum = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(genericTypeArgs);

                    if (genEnum.IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                    {
                        var propVal = (IList<string>)prop.GetValue(testType, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, null);

                        foreach (var item in propVal)
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestType
    {
        public IList<string> GenList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I marked your question as answer. Actually I will very likely not look at the problem again, because I changed my working environment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

An attribute is never a `List<>`. So `oa.GetType() == typeof(List<>)` will always be false.

Perhaps you wanted to get fields with `GetFields()`, or properties with `GetProperties()` instead of getting custom attributes.

You might also want to check if the type implements `IEnumerable<T>` instead of checking if it is identical to `List<T>`.

Comment: I added the complete code now, where I will try out Myles McConnels recommendations.